# Printing out the index within a line and number of line the word is found

Tags: java, algorithm, brute-force

So basically I created a code that imports a text file containing words, and when i enter a word into the code, the program will find if the word is within the text file that I imported.

What I finally wanted to do was find the index number (within the line it was found) and the line number the word was found. I can the code to print out the index number out of the total text but not within the line it was found, by doing

```
String indexnum = s1;
System.out.println("Matches at index : " + indexnum.lastIndexOf(s2));
```

which prints something like

'Matches at index : 2949232'

What I would like it to print is something like...

'matches at index 26 in the line 4441'

any ideas how i could do so.. im honestly running out of ideas.

Comment: You can split the string by newlines and then iterate over the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `Files.readString()`? I'd recommend going line by line with a scanner or similar:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filepath)); // be sure to catch or throw the exception
for (int lineNum = 1; in.hasNextLine(); lineNum++) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    int index = line.indexOf(s2);
    if (index >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Match found on line " + lineNum + ", column " + (index + 1));
    }
}
```

But if you need it stored as one big blob of text, maybe you could take advantage of this version of [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)), which takes a starting index for the search.

```
for (int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0, lineNum = 1; true; lineNum++) {

    endIndex = s1.indexOf("\n", startIndex);
    String line;
    if (endIndex < 0) {
        // No newline found. Continue to the end of the string.
        line = s1.substring(startIndex);
    } else {
        line = s1.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }

    int matchIndex = line.indexOf(s2);
    if (matchIndex >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Match found on line " + lineNum + ", column " + (matchIndex + 1));
    }

    if (endIndex < 0) {
        break;
    }

    startIndex = endIndex + 1;
}
```